# avoid google map markers (symbols) overlap

Tags: google-maps-api-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I cluster markers without overlap with google maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781183/how-can-i-cluster-markers-without-overlap-with-google-maps)

I have a different positions on the map, different type of `Incidents` could happens at the same time in a same point. Now all of these markers (which are default CIRCLEs) overlapping on each other, if different types on incidents happens on a same point. The scale of the CIRCLEs are also dynamic, based on the number of incidents which happened there.

So, is there any practical solution to **Detect** or **Avoid** these markers overlaps on each other? (consider scales are dynamic)

I've already-generated JSON data files (by Cron jobs, from Database) but I have access to the database also, so I can make custom queries if needed. I use google maps api v.3 also.

Thanks in advance. :)

**Update:**

regarding [MarkerClusterer](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html), unfortunately I can't see how it could avoid overlaps? It's designed to manage large amount of markers: *The library creates and manages per-zoom-level clusters for large amounts of markers.* but in my case, imagine I have only 2 markers, but they're gonna overlap each other. So, MarkerClusterer could do anything with that also?

regarding [Overlapping Marker Spiderfier](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/), I prefer to do it manually or natively by Google Maps API (if it's possible), instead of using third-party libraries. But might go for that eventually, if couldn't find any better solution.

Comment: Have you looked into [Markerclusterer](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/examples/simple_example.html)?

Comment: And plenty more: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=google+maps+cluster&submit=search

Comment: oh, I didn't know the term ... let me look at your suggestions, thanks BTW! :)