# What is the correct process of storing equal geocoding data?

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, google-geocoder

I have a site where people mark their stores on a map I run with Google Maps (if it even matters). Now there are cases where stores get tagged in the same Shopping Center, which obviously can have several different stores tagged in it. To be more specific let's say I own an Adidas store at Midtown Shopping Center in LA which is with `Latitude 34.0475747` and `Longtitude -118.3403492`. A Nike owner has a store at the same Shopping Center so when he marks his businness, there will be two identical pins on the map and the user experience will be spoiled. This happens since I use the Google Maps address autocomplete, then have the information transformed into geocode and saved to mySQL.

So how do I process geocoding data that already exists on my map in a way I can display the two dropped pins nearby each other, make the pins clickable (so a text field can expand and show people the info they are supposed to see) but yet both stores will be tagged in the area of the same Shopping Center?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I cluster markers without overlap with google maps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781183/how-can-i-cluster-markers-without-overlap-with-google-maps)

Comment: Perhaps look at the [Overlapping MarkerSpiderfier](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-maps-api-3%5D+OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier)

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of a geohash (http://geohash.org/)?

This essentially takes two coordinates and creates a precision(positional) based hash from them.

So the longer the hash the more precise it is.

You could hash the coordinates and then just say that at a certain level of precision, the results are the same.