# Move markers by a specific distance in meters from where they are

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I have a collection of items and some of them may have the same coordinates.
As a result they are displayed as 1 marker in Google Maps since the markers are painted one on top of each other.
To address this I tried to "move" those markers by a few meters so that the markers do not collide.
I would like to move them to a 5 meters from where their location is.
I did the following following another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20490654/more-than-one-marker-on-same-place-markerclusterer):

```
double newLat = item.getLatitude() + (Math.random() - .005) / 15000;    
double newLon = item.getLongitude() + (Math.random() - .005) / 15000;
```

The problem is that this moves the items a bit but it seems that some are moved by 4m others by 3m and I would like if possible to ensure that I will be between 4-6 meters (min/max)
How can I change my formula to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the best option could be using the [`SphericalUtil. computeOffset`](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.html#computeOffset-LatLng-double-double-) method from the [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/):

> **computeOffset**
>
> ```
> public static LatLng computeOffset(LatLng from,
>                                double distance,
>                                double heading)
> ```
>
> Returns the LatLng resulting from moving a distance from an origin in the specified heading (expressed in degrees clockwise from north).
>
> Parameters:
>
> **from** - The LatLng from which to start.
>
> **distance** - The distance to travel.
>
> **heading** - The heading in degrees clockwise from north.

In your case you can set the `distance` to be 5 meters and randomise the `heading` parameter to be something between 0 and 360 degrees:

```
Random r = new Random();
int randomHeading = r.nextInt(360);
LatLng newLatLng = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(oldLatLng, 5, randomHeading);
```

Comment: The javadoc does not say that the distance is in meters does it?

Comment: No, it doesn't, but you can compute the distance between `oldLatLng` and `newLatLng` using `SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(oldLatLng, newLatLng)` (which according to the documentation returns the distance in meters) and you will see that the distance is 5 meters

Comment: I did and it is so but how did you assume that it is in meters? Is it standard in the Google Maps API to use meters?

Comment: As far as I know all the classes and methods from the Google Maps Android API Utility Library uses meters as the unit. Anyway your can take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.java)