# How to display duplicate maker in cluster here map

Tags: here-api

I am using here map and I use clustering. But I have problem for displaying maker whose cordinates  are same /dublicate . When I zoom in clustering  , unfortunately the makers are not visible but cluster is still visible. How to display these makers when cluster is zoomed ?

My clustering options is as following

```
var clusteredDataProvider = new H.clustering.Provider(dataPoints, {
                clusteringOptions : {
                    eps : 16,
                    minWeight : 2
                },
                theme : new PusulaClusterTheme()
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same issue. If you absolutely need the markers to show the exact very same spot up to the inch so to speak, then I don't know what you could do. But we wanted to show markers for each house on a street and sometimes we had multiple families in a house so we could not get the multiple ones to properly show.

We opened a ticket with HERE and this was their reply:

> "...when you are placing multiple markers at the same geo-point, it is
>   just that they are stacked one on top of the other. Since they are all
>   at the same coordinate only the top most one will be displayed.   So
>   to enable multiple marker to be shown at the same coordinate, you will
>   need to have some logic to avoid overlapping of markers. There is no
>   method straight off the shelf in JS API that can do this for you, but maybe
>   you can use the method [map.getObjectsat(X,Y)](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api/h-map.html#h-map__getobjectsat) to check if there are
>   already any markers at the point. If there is an existing one, then use
>   some logic to slightly change the coordinate value of the new marker
>   to be added at the point.

We ended up copying a solution we found here on Stackoverflow [see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20490654/more-than-one-marker-on-same-place-markerclusterer/20626641#20626641) that was written for Google Maps, but is just as relevant here with HERE. It uses a function to randomly change the last digit or 2 of the coordinates if they are multiple, and that way all your multiple coordinates will be a little bit unique and spaced out.