# Here Map : How to differentiate between two markers at same location

Tags: ios, swift, here-api

How can we differentiate among multiple NMAMapMarker at same location. 
As we have marker.userdata property for google markers but how to manage data for markers in Here Maps.

Comment: save marker position then match position  when tapping on marker

Comment: I have 2 markers with different model (custom objects) on same NMAGeoCoordinate.

Comment: I don't know about NMAMapMarker I m using GMSmarker

Comment: See my answer to similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44250572/4210806

Answer (score 1):

When you are placing multiple markers at the same geo-point, they are stacked on top of the other. Since they are all at the same coordinate, only the top most one will be displayed. To enable multiple marker to be shown at the same coordinate, you will need to have some logic to slightly shift the position of markers. For example check if there is already a marker at the point, if there is an existing one, then use some logic to slightly change the coordinate value of the new marker to be added at the point.